# SwiftUI toolbar principal textfield loses focus on text editing

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have to put search text field to navigation bar. I used `.toolbar` modifier to add textfield, but when I type text in this field it looses focus. You can see at 10 sec video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z00eEpH2JpQ

```
import SwiftUI
import PhoneNumberKit


struct SelectRegionView: View {
    // MARK: Variables
    var countries: [RegionRowData] {
        // getting list of countries from PhoneNumberKit
    }
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    // MARK: Body
    var body: some View {
        if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            List {
                makeListElements()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .principal) {
                    TextField("Search", text: $searchText)
                }
            })
        } else {
            List {
                makeListElements()
            }
            .navigationBarTitle("", displayMode: .inline)
            .add(searchBar)
        }
            
    }
    
    
    // MARK: Functions
    private func makeListElements() -> some View {
        return ForEach(countries.filter({ rowData in
            self.searchText.isEmpty || rowData.name.localizedUppercase.contains(self.searchText.localizedUppercase)
        }), id: \.name) { country in
            makeCell(country: country)
        }
    }
    
    private func makeCell(country: RegionRowData) -> some View {
        ...
    }
    
}
```

Why does field loses focus?

Demo project available at github: https://github.com/undestroyer/swiftUISearchIssue

Comment: Replicated code works fine with Xcode 13 / iOS 15. Which env do you use? Also probably the reason might be in other your code (not provided here).

Comment: @Asperi, I removed all extra code and created single view application. The problem still exists. Can you please check repo https://github.com/undestroyer/swiftUISearchIssue ?